# Why throwing the TokenNotFoundException or AccessDeniedException brings to login page in Symfony2?

Tags: exception, redirect, symfony

I have two "simple questions" that concern the exceptions in Symfony2.
Here follows the description of the problem.
I throw a **TokenNotFoundException** (or a **AccessDeniedException**) into a controller. If that exception is thrown, then the framework automatically redirects to the *login page*.

1. Why?
2. How can I customize the page to be called after that an exception is throws?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for question 1 :

Look at the [Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php) class. The [onKernelException](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L75) method does the job...

Comment: Ok! I understood now! Any idea of how to solve the second question?

Comment: Do you think that I need to write a service to replace the onKernelException as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465751/symfony2-manipulate-request-response-from-the-kernel-exception-listener ?

Comment: I think that the Symfony2 framework should not simply forward the user to the login page! Some error should be displayed! I'm going to see how to set the $error object with the customized message to the Security Context.

Comment: If the error is a mistake by typing login or password, an error message is displayed. If it's a technical error (example: user destroys its cookies), it's redirected to the login page without error message. It seems simple for user, no need to tell her/him that "his token is not found", it's not a relevant information for a user...

Comment: Mhhh! Well, it seems a reasonable answer. Thanks PéCé!